# Creating a variable on database to hold global stats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, variables

Let's pretend I've got a social network.
I'm always showing to the user how many users are registered and have activated their profile.
So, everytime a single user logs in, it goes to DB and make a:

```
select count(*) from users where status = 'activated'
```

so if 5.000 users logs in, or simply refreshes the page, it will make 5.000 requests to SQL above.
I was wondering if is better to have a variable some place(that I still have no idea where to put) that everytime a user activates his profile will add 1 and then, when I want to show how many users are registered to that social network, I'll only get the value of this variable.

How can I make this? Is it really a better solution to what I've got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an indexed view, that SQL Server will automatically maintain:

```
create table dbo.users (
    ID int not null,
    Activated bit not null
)
go
create view dbo.user_status_stats (Activated,user_count)
with schemabinding
as
    select Activated,COUNT_BIG(*) from dbo.users group by Activated
go
create unique clustered index IX_user_status_stats on dbo.user_status_stats (Activated)
go
```

This just has two possible statuses, but could expand to more using a different data type. As I say, in this case, SQL Server will maintain the counts behind the scenes, so you can just query the view:

```
SELECT user_count from user_status_stats with (NOEXPAND) where Activated = 1
```

and it won't have to query the underlying table. You need to use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint on editions below (Enterprise/Developer).

---

Although as @Jim suggested, doing a COUNT(*) against an index when the index column(s) can satisfy the query criteria using equality comparisons should be pretty quick also.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same thing? I would have to make 5.000 selects to the view it anyway. Don't blame me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the same thing to me :(

Comment: @pringlesinn - it's the simplest thing to do, *if you're wanting to keep this information in SQL Server*. Or to turn your query around, wouldn't holding this in a "variable somewhere" require 5000 queries of that variable? If you don't want to run any queries against the database, keep the most recent figure in an application cache, but don't look to SQL to maintain it for you.

Comment: I wanted to have this full select count blah blah blah once every 30 seconds, updating the value on a single column, and than i'd have to make the 5.000 queries to select this value and not a select count(*) again, does it make a big difference as I think it does or is it basically same thing?

Comment: @pringlesinn - the view I've shown in my answer is maintained by SQL Server - it updates the `COUNT(*)` values whenever rows are inserted or deleted from the users table, or have their status changed. If you query the view (using the final query I've got in my answer), it doesn't perform a further `COUNT(*)` - it already has that value computed; or to put it another way, what I've shown above is more efficient than what you're suggesting, and involves writing less code.

Comment: so what you're saying is that the view stores a cached value? something like this?

Comment: @pringlesinn - If you want to put it that way, yes, except the cache is maintained automatically by SQL Server - if you insert 5 new users, 3 of whom are Activated, 2 not, SQL Server knows to update the view and change the count by +3 for the Activated row, and +2 for the non-Activated row.

Comment: I've got it! Thank you very much, now I'll try to convince the rest that this is the best solution hahahaha

Comment: @pringlesinn. For you to use Indexed Views you must be running one of the top-end versions of SQL Server, Enterprise or Datacenter. If you are using Standard, Web, Workgroup, or Express, then this is not an option for you. Also, if you are using the Developer edition to test with, it is feature identical to Enterprise.

Comment: @Jim - you can use indexed views just fine in lower editions - but you have to use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint, as I mentioned when I first posted this answer, and is still there.

Comment: @Damien, oops, miss that one.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already guessed - it's not a great idea to calculate this value every time someone hits the site.

You could do as you suggest, and update a central value as users are added, although you'll have to ensure that you don't end up with two processes updating the number simultaneously.

Alternatively you could have a job which runs your SQL routinely and updates the central 'user count' value.

Alternatively #2, you could use something like MemCache to hold the calculated value for a period of time, and then when the cache expires, recalculate it again.

Comment: That's what I wonder how to do hahahah, I'd create a table to stores only this? And for updating this value, I'd do a trigger? I have never done this before.

Comment: Yes, depending on other values you want to pre-calculate, you could create a `stats` or `globals` table with a `name` and a `value` column, such that you could store `name='USERS'` `value=XXX` - or if you only want to store a few values, you could have a table with a single row, and fields for each of your values.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options you could consider:

1) like you say, maintain a global count each time a profile is activated to save the hit on the users table each time. You could just store that count in a "Stats" table and then query that value from there.

2) don't show the actual "live" count, show a count that's "pretty much up to date" - e.g. cache the count in your application and have the value expire periodically so you then requery the count less frequently. Or if you store the count in a "Stats" table per above, you could have a scheduled job that updates the count every hour, instead of every time a profile is activated.

Depends whether you want to show the exact figure in real-time or whether you can live with a delay. Obviously, data volumes matter too - if you have a large database, then having a slightly out of date cached value could be worth while.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely SQL Server standpoint, no, you are not going to find a better way of doing this. Unless, perhaps, your social network is Facebook sized. Denormalizing your data design (such as keeping a count in a separate table) will lead to possible sources of the data getting out of sync. It doesn't have to get out of sync if it is coded properly, but it can...

Just make sure that you have an index on Status. At which point SQL will not scan the table for the count, but it will scan the **index** instead. The index will be much smaller (that is, more data will fit in a disk page). If you were to convert your status to an int, smallint, or tinyint you would get even more index leaves in a disk page and thus much less IO. To get your description ('activated', etc.), use a reference table. The reference table would be so small, SQL would just keep the whole thing in RAM after the first access.

Now, if you still think this is too much overhead (and it should't be) you could come up with hybrid method. You could store your count in a separate table (which SQL would keep in RAM if it is just the one record) or assuming your site is in asp.net you could create an Application variable to keep track of the count. You could increment it in Session_Start and decrement it in Session_End. But, you will have to come up with a way of making the the increment and decrement thread safe so two sessions don't try and update the value at the same time.

Comment: What if I make a count(*) every 30 seconds for example and stores that count column on a table? It would never have the problem to conflict with anything else. It's what they want me to do, actually..

Comment: @pringlesinn: Yes, that would work. It would always be just an estimate, but if that is all you are looking for, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [**Global Temporary table**](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables). You will always get fast retrieval. Even
if you are setting 30 seconds ping. The [**Example Trigger Link1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), [**Example Trigger Link2**](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15510) will maintain such activities in this table.

Comment: I forgot about ##temp tables. Interesting application. You just have to remember that it gets dropped automatically when the last connection that used it closes.

Comment: Sorry, did not mention it explicitly. Creation of Global temporary table will be manual. I think now it makes sense.